# Removing € from a string and converting the string into an int using python to calculate the average price per year

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am scraping a website and the code gives me all the information I want however when scraping it also gives me the "€" symbol with the price. So I want to be able to have the price as a int and remove the "€" symbol so I can Calculate the average car price per year. It does give me the ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'price' but when I try look at other questions on this website with the answer the solutions don't work for me. Year is also a string so would it make sense to convert the year to an int as well so I can do equations?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={}&per-page=12"

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).text, "html.parser")

    for car in soup.select(".car"):
        info = car.select_one(".top-info").get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
        info = info.split("|")
        if len(info) == 4:
            make, model, year, price = info
        else:
            make, year, price = info
            model = "N/A"
        dealer_name = car.select_one(".dealer-name h6").get_text(
            strip=True, separator=" "
        )
        address = car.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True)

        features = {}
        for feature in car.select(".car--features li"):
            k = feature.img["src"].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
            v = feature.span.text
            features[f"feature_{k}"] = v

        all_data.append(
            {
                "make": make,
                "model": model,
                "year": year,
                "price": price,
                "dealer_name": dealer_name,
                "address": address,
                "url": "https://jammer.ie"
                + car.select_one("a[href*=vehicle]")["href"],
                **features,
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
# prints sample data to screen:
print(df.tail().to_markdown(index=False))
# saves all data to CSV
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

I tired converting using

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols= ['price','year'])

print(type("price"))
print(int("price"))
```

But this did not work out for me. I also tired converting it to a float as well which did not work too.

Comment: `import re; re.finall(r'\d+', "$123.45")` gives `[123, 45]`. Hopefully that gets you a little closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have data in pandas DataFrame you can do:

```py
#... your code

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

df["price"] = df["price"].str.replace(r"[€,]", "", regex=True)
df["price"] = pd.to_numeric(df["price"], errors="coerce")

df["year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["year"], errors="coerce")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             make     model  year    price                           dealer_name        address                                                          url feature_speed feature_engine feature_transmission feature_door-icon1 feature_petrol5 feature_hatchback      feature_owner feature_paint
0             BMW  5 Series  2012  14250.0              JOS Jack O Sullivan Cars    Co. Wexford           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/150168-bmw-5-series-2012  103000 miles     2.0 litres            Automatic            0 doors          Diesel            Saloon                NaN           NaN
1         Citroen        C3  2003   1999.0                     Somerville Motors      Co. Meath             https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167272-citroen-c3-2003   74000 miles     1.4 litres            Automatic            5 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  8 previous owners          Grey
2      Volkswagen   Touareg  2017  29958.0                  Holden Motor Company     Co. Dublin     https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167271-volkswagen-touareg-2017  145000 miles     3.0 litres            Automatic            5 doors          Diesel               SUV  3 previous owners         Black
3            Audi        A6  2010   7950.0            Roskeen Cars & Commercials       Co. Cork                https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167270-audi-a6-2010  174921 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel            Estate  1 previous owners          Grey
4      Volkswagen    Passat  2012   6999.0                     Somerville Motors      Co. Meath      https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167269-volkswagen-passat-2012  150000 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            4 doors          Diesel            Saloon  7 previous owners        Silver
5        Vauxhall  Insignia  2016  12499.0                     ARTHUR AUTO SALES   Co. Limerick      https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167268-vauxhall-insignia-2016  127000 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  1 previous owners         Black
6            Audi        A6  2022      NaN           Audi Approved Plus Kilkenny   Co. Kilkenny                https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167267-audi-a6-2022     932 miles     2.0 litres            Automatic                NaN          Diesel            Saloon                NaN          Grey
7      Volkswagen      Polo  2018  14999.0                    O Neills Car Sales      Co. Meath        https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167266-volkswagen-polo-2018   73868 miles     1.0 litres               Manual            5 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  1 previous owners         White
8            Audi        A1  2022      NaN           Audi Approved Plus Kilkenny   Co. Kilkenny                https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167265-audi-a1-2022     932 miles     1.0 litres               Manual                NaN          Petrol         Hatchback                NaN          Grey
9      Volkswagen      Golf  2014  24999.0                    O Neills Car Sales      Co. Meath        https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167263-volkswagen-golf-2014   82523 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            3 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  1 previous owners         Black
10        Peugeot      5008  2014  13950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167260-peugeot-5008-2014   47000 miles     1.6 litres            Automatic            5 doors          Petrol               MPV  1 previous owners         White
11           Audi        A4  2014  14950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin                https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167259-audi-a4-2014  120000 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            4 doors          Diesel            Saloon  2 previous owners         White
12     Volkswagen       up!  2013      NaN                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin          https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167257-volkswagen-up-2013   90101 miles     1.0 litres               Manual            4 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  3 previous owners         White
13           Ford    Fiesta  2010   5950.0                           Car Options     Co. Dublin            https://jammer.ie/vehicle/111682-ford-fiesta-2010  113144 miles     1.4 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  4 previous owners        Silver
14       Vauxhall  Insignia  2015   8950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin      https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167256-vauxhall-insignia-2015  111849 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            0 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  1 previous owners         Black
15         Nissan   X-Trail  2016  18950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin         https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167255-nissan-x-trail-2016   83887 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            4 doors          Diesel               MPV  2 previous owners         White
16        Hyundai       i10  2016   8950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin            https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167254-hyundai-i10-2016   59031 miles     1.0 litres               Manual            4 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  4 previous owners        Silver
17        Peugeot      3008  2017  23950.0                        PRESTIGE AUTOS     Co. Dublin           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167253-peugeot-3008-2017   74566 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  1 previous owners         Black
18            Kia  Sportage  2019      NaN                              Kirwan's    Co. Wexford           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167252-kia-sportage-2019   56008 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel               MPV  2 previous owners          Grey
19         Toyota   Corolla  2007   2950.0                       LPD Commercials     Co. Dublin         https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167251-toyota-corolla-2007  115000 miles     1.4 litres               Manual            5 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  3 previous owners          Blue
20        Peugeot   Partner  2012   5950.0                       LPD Commercials     Co. Dublin        https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167250-peugeot-partner-2012  118000 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel               MPV  3 previous owners          Blue
21           Audi        A6  2006   2950.0                       LPD Commercials     Co. Dublin                https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167249-audi-a6-2006  130000 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            6 doors          Diesel            Saloon  3 previous owners         Black
22           Opel  Insignia  2011   4950.0                     Blue Diamond Cars       Co. Cork          https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167248-opel-insignia-2011  153000 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            4 doors          Diesel            Saloon  6 previous owners         Black
23        Hyundai     Bayon  2023  26545.0                          Doran Motors   Co. Monaghan          https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167247-hyundai-bayon-2023           NaN     1.2 litres               Manual            5 doors          Petrol               SUV                NaN           Red
24     Volkswagen     Jetta  2014   9950.0  Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident       Co. Cork       https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167246-volkswagen-jetta-2014  112000 miles     1.2 litres               Manual            4 doors          Petrol            Saloon  2 previous owners         Black
25          Lexus        CT  2011   9950.0                          Weirs Motors     Co. Dublin               https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167245-lexus-ct-2011  139210 miles     1.8 litres            Automatic            5 doors             NaN         Hatchback  4 previous owners         White
26            BMW  5 Series  2018  31995.0             Auto Vision Motor Company     Co. Dublin           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/159883-bmw-5-series-2018   78646 miles     2.0 litres            Automatic            4 doors          Hybrid            Saloon  1 previous owners          Grey
27            Kia       N/A  2012   6950.0  Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident       Co. Cork                    https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167244-kia-2012  115000 miles     1.6 litres               Manual            3 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  1 previous owners          Grey
28     Volkswagen  Scirocco  2015  18950.0                          Weirs Motors     Co. Dublin    https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167242-volkswagen-scirocco-2015   34928 miles     2.0 litres               Manual            3 doors          Diesel             Coupe                NaN         Black
29     Volkswagen       Fox  2010   4800.0                      Pat & Jason Ryan  Co. Waterford         https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167241-volkswagen-fox-2010  150095 miles     1.2 litres               Manual            3 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  3 previous owners          Grey
30        Peugeot      3008  2019  30950.0                          Gowan Motors     Co. Dublin           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167240-peugeot-3008-2019   20989 miles     1.5 litres            Automatic            5 doors          Diesel               SUV  1 previous owners          Grey
31     Volkswagen    Beetle  2017  20950.0                    Grange Road Motors     Co. Dublin      https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167239-volkswagen-beetle-2017   39023 miles     1.2 litres            Automatic            3 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  1 previous owners           Red
32  Mercedes-Benz   E-Class  2012  13950.0                           Car Options     Co. Dublin  https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167238-mercedes-benz-e-class-2012  119487 miles     2.1 litres            Automatic            4 doors          Diesel            Saloon  2 previous owners        Silver
33            Kia    Optima  2016  16500.0                         BG Motors Ltd      Co. Kerry             https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167237-kia-optima-2016   86994 miles     1.7 litres               Manual            5 doors          Diesel            Estate  2 previous owners         Black
34     Volkswagen    Beetle  2007   4950.0                        Moloney Motors     Co. Dublin      https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167236-volkswagen-beetle-2007  103150 miles     1.4 litres               Manual            2 doors          Petrol       Convertible  6 previous owners          Blue
35            BMW  5 Series  2019      NaN             Cieran McConnon Car Sales   Co. Monaghan           https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167235-bmw-5-series-2019   34500 miles     2.0 litres            Automatic            4 doors          Diesel            Saloon  1 previous owners          Blue
36           Opel     Corsa  2011   6999.0                    Michael Tynan Cars     Co. Dublin             https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167234-opel-corsa-2011   59032 miles     1.2 litres               Manual            5 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  3 previous owners         Black
37           Ford     Focus  2018  21999.0                    Michael Tynan Cars     Co. Dublin             https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167233-ford-focus-2018   31691 miles     1.5 litres               Manual            4 doors          Diesel         Hatchback  2 previous owners          Blue
38     Volkswagen      Polo  2021  22222.0                    Michael Tynan Cars     Co. Dublin        https://jammer.ie/vehicle/167232-volkswagen-polo-2021   10573 miles     1.0 litres               Manual            5 doors          Petrol         Hatchback  1 previous owners           Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function for that and apply it on new/existing column,
like so:

```
pd = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": [1,2,2,3,4],
    "prices": ["1€", "2.2€", "5€","66€", "999€"]
    }
)

# Use own function to create custom column
def remove_currency_sign(price: str, sign:str = "€")->int:
    return int(price.replace(sign,""))

pd["new_col"] = pd["prices"].apply(remove_currency_sign)
print(pd)
```